Run Ansys using powershell
I am trying to run Ansys using powershell.
I am completely new in powershell environment.
The only help I have got from Ansys website and different online forum is running ansys using the following command line prompt (cmd)
%ans_path% -b -np %num_proc% -j %job% -run %run% -i therm.inp -o trun.out
where
%ans_path% , %num_proc% etc. are variables defined early.
Reference: https://deepthoughtdocs.flinders.edu.au/en/latest/software/ansys.html
How do I run this same code in Powershell?
or Do I have to invoke CMD from powershell to run this code?
Would appreciate help any direction!

It is unlikely that cmd.exe would need to be invoked. A PowerShell command might be:
& "C:\Program Files\ans\ansys212.exe" -b -np 4 -j 'the_job' -run 'the_run' -i therm.inp -o trun.out

This assumes the the -np parameter is numeric and that -j and -run are strings that name the job and run respectively.
If you wanted to do it "just like cmd," then you might:
$AnsPath = 'C:\Program Files\ans\ansys212.exe'
$NumProcessors = 4
$JobName = 'the_job'
$RunName = 'the_run'
& $AnsPath -b -np $NumProcessors -j $JobName -run $RunName -i therm.inp -o trun.out

